# Maven dependency listed in pom.xml, but not recognizing methods in Package com.espertech.esperio

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, esper

Maven dependency listed in pom.xml, but not recognizing methods in Package com.espertech.esperio

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.espertech/esperio -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.espertech</groupId>
            <artifactId>esperio</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

getting error in intelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol esperio

Comment: Please run a Maven build `mvn clean verify` and report the error you get.

Comment: A$ mvn clean verify
...Could not resolve dependencies for project ... Failed to collect dependencies at com.espertech:esperio:jar:3.3.0 -> opentick:opentick:jar:07-04-08: Failed to read artifact descriptor for opentick:opentick:jar:07-04-08: Could not transfer artifact opentick:opentick:pom:07-04-08 from/to maven2-repository.dev.java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://maven-repository...